# C# preprocessor directive or conditional for differentiating between Visual Studio 2012 and 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, conditional-statements, preprocessor-directive

I have some C# code that only works in Visual Studio 2012 but I also use Visual Studio 2010 on the same codebase. Is there a preprocessor directive or a conditional I can use to isolate the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No built in pre-processor directive as far as I know, but there is an MSBuild variable.

Open the project file (unload it in Solution Explorer, then click edit) and add the following after the main set of property declarations.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);VS_10;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);VS_11;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can then use the `VS_10` (VS 2010) or `VS_11` (VS 2012) preproc directives.